# Bind a function accepting three arguments and accepts the middle one

Tags: javascript

I have a function with three arguments

```js
function funcy(arg1, arg2, arg3){
   return (arg1+arg3)*arg2
}
```

I can bind this as follows

```js
const funcybound = funcy.bind({}, 1/*arg1*/, 2/*arg2*/)
funcybound(3);//arg3
```

Is there any way to create a bound function such that it accepts the middle argument, fixing the first and last in place

Maybe something like this

```js
const funcybound = funcy.bind({}, 1/*arg1*/,null, 2/*arg3*/)
funcybound(2);//arg2
```

I know i can return  a function that does this, but just curious if i can do this with just the bind method

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `Function.prototype.bind`.

Comment: You cannot, the `.bind()` method only allows you to define the leading arguments of a function, it doesn't allow you to define arbitrary arguments to bind.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any signficant performance difference in  `bind` and just creating a closure 
`const funcBind= (arg3)=>{
func(1,2,arg3)
}`

and `func.bind({},1,2)`